# $P( \lim_{n \to \infty} {1 \over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(X_k) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)$ $dx) = 1$

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_k, k=1,2,3,...$ be independent random variables which are uniformly distributed on [0,1] and $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and bounded.

I want to show that $$\mathbb P\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} {1 \over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(X_k) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx\right) = 1$$

I am sure that I have to use one of the limit theorems but I don't know what the exact approach is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that since $f$ is continuous its measureable. Thus $f(X_i)$ are independent. Now according to famous theorem, $\lim \frac1n  \sum f(X)$ converges to $E[f(x)]$. What do you have on the right side of the equality?

Comment: Is this correct: With the strong law of large numbers, it follows that:

$lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} f(X_j) = \mathbb E(f(X_1)) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)$ $ \boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]} = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$ almost-surely? (Step 2 as the formal definition of this expectation value).

Comment: I would say that the integral with $1_{[0,1]}$ is unnecessary and just confusing, but otherwise looks good! @Pazu

Comment: Would the statement be also correct, if $f$ was only measureable and bounded almost everywhere on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Pazu Yes, because​ the expectation would still be bounded, don't you agree?

Comment: Thanks now I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\mathbb{E}[f(X_k)] = \displaystyle\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx$ for all $k$. What does the strong law of large numbers tell us?